# How LeakyReLU layer works without setting the number of units?

Tags: keras, deep-learning, activation-function, relu

When building Sequential model, I notice  there is a difference between adding `relu` layer and `LeakyReLU` layer.

```
test = Sequential()
test.add(Dense(1024, activation="relu"))
test.add(LeakyReLU(0.2))
```

1. Why cant we add layer with activation = "`LeakyReLU`" ? (LeakyReLU is not a string which keras can work with)
2. When adding `relu` layer, we set the number of units (1024 in my example)
   Why can't we do the same for `LeakyReLU` ?

I was sure that the different between `relu` and `LeakyReLU` is the method behavior, but it seems more than that.

Answer (score 3):

1. We could specify the activation function in the dense layer itself, by using aliases like `activation='relu'`, which would use the default keras parameters for relu. There is no such aliases available in keras, for LeakyRelu activation function. We have to use [`tf.keras.layers.LeakyRelu`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/LeakyReLU) or [`tf.nn.leaky_relu`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/leaky_relu).
2. We cannot set number of units in Relu layer, it just takes the previous output tensor and applies the relu activation function on it. You have specified the number of units for the Dense layer not the relu layer.  When we specify `Dense(1024, activation="relu")` we multiply the inputs with weights, add biases and apply relu function on the output (all of this is mentioned on a single line). From the method mentioned on step 1, this process is done in 2 stages firstly to multiply weights, add biases and then to apply the LeakyRelu activation function (mentioned in 2 lines).

Comment: Lets say I want to build a model with 3 layers: first layer with 1024 units and relu activation. second layer with 512 units and leakyrelu activation and last layer with 1 unit and sigmoid activation. How can I build it ?

Answer (score 0):

```
    import tensorflow as tf
    test = Sequential()
    test.add(Dense(1024, input_dim=784, activation="relu", name="First"))
    test.add(Dense(512,  activation=tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.01), name="middle"))
    test.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', name="Last"))
    test.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer="adam")
    print(test.summary())
```

ouput:

```
Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
First (Dense)                (None, 1024)              803840    
_________________________________________________________________
middle (Dense)               (None, 512)               524800    
_________________________________________________________________
Last (Dense)                 (None, 1)                 513       
=================================================================
```